Create two jenkins pipelines with one script
I have the following problem - I have one jenkins pipeline script which is created by a seed job.
From that pipeline script I would like to create two pipelines - one created from master-branch and the other one with a parameter branch.
Thanks, any help is appreciated is welcome.
Best regards,
Hellge

Use the branch Parameter in the Pipeline Script:
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'BRANCH_NAME', defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Branch to build')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${params.BRANCH_NAME}"]], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://your-repo-url.git']]])
            }
        }
        // Other stages
    }
}


